# Python QThread возможно ли изменить переменную в потоке из основной программы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, qt5, pyqt5

QThread вынесен в отдельный файл слушает com порт (весовое оборудование) и через слот передает полученный результат в основную программу которая получает сигнал и выводит в поле, нужно вывести максимум который был на весах, я его нахожу и вывожу, но возникает проблема:
если рассчитывать максимум в потоке, то он тоже отлично выводиться через слот, однако когда необходимо сделать скажем сброс на кнопку и взвесить новый товар тут возникает потребность либо как-то обнулить максимум послав его из основной программы в поток, либо остановить поток и запустить заново где в инициализации потока максиму сброситься

Comment: А лучше всего возможно ли как то получить значение переменной которая передается в слоте ? Тогда бы я смог оперировать данными с com порта в основной программе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Так попробуйте**

```
import os
import sys
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class ComPort(QThread):
    value = pyqtSignal(int)
    r = True
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        for i in range(1, 100, 1):
            if self.r == False:
                break
            self.value.emit(i)
            sleep(0.1)

    def reset(self):
        self.r = False

class Window(QMainWindow):
    value = pyqtSignal(bool)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Многопоточность сигналы слоты")
        self.setGeometry(500, 300, 350, 60)

        button = QPushButton("Сброс", self)
        button.setGeometry(0, 30, 50, 30)

        self.progress_bar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progress_bar.setValue(10)
        self.progress_bar.setGeometry(0, 0, 350, 30)

        self.com_port = ComPort()
        self.com_port.start()
        self.com_port.value.connect(self.progress)

        button.clicked.connect(self.com_port.reset)


    def progress(self, value):
        self.progress_bar.setValue(value)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Меня навела на мысль строка кода предложенного Александром, конкретно строка:

button.clicked.connect(self.com_port.reset)

Вызывающая функцию потока из основной программы GUI, в которой я смог обнулить максимум в потоке, спасибо Александру